# Scale the pod on the same node where EBS is attached

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rancher, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-helm

I want to scale the pods in the same worker node where already one EBS volume associated with pod is attached. How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can configure PodAffinity to schedule new pods only on the same node that it is already scheduled (obviously not in case of first one).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity-beta-feature